# Basic Java Dice program - trouble finding longest streak

Tags: java, arrays, dice

I'm currently working on a basic (and as I can see, frequently assigned) java project in which I'm to create a program that simulates the rolling of dice. In my project I'm only simulating the rolling of two six sided die. Arrays need to be used in completing this task.

So far I have try/catch block that asks the user for the amount of rolls they would like to simulate and ensures that they give an integer input. This in turn creates the length of the array for the dice simulator. Up to this point my code works but now I am stuck on how to find the longest streak of consecutive sums within that array.

I'm pretty sure I need to be comparing my dieSum value for each roll against itself, and if dieSum == dieSum then increasing a variable for my current streak by 1. I'm just unsure of how to do this, I suspect I may have a problem because my dieSum variable isn't being stored into an array.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class RollThoseDice {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("MyNameHere");
    System.out.println("ThirdProgram \n");

    //Variable listing and initialization
    int rollTotal = 0; //number of trials
    int dieSum; //sum of the outcome of both dice per roll

    //Try - Catch block to ensure positive integer input from user for rollTotal
    System.out.println("***Welcome to the Dice Roll Probability Generator***");
    while (true){
        System.out.println("Enter how many dice rolls you would like to simulate: ");
        try {
            rollTotal = kbd.nextInt() + 1;
            break;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Please only enter a positive integer. Try again. ");
            kbd.next();

        }
    }


    int die1[] = new int[rollTotal]; //Variable for the first die
    int die2[] = new int[rollTotal]; //Variable for the second die


    int[] diceArray = new int[rollTotal];   
    for (int i=1; i<diceArray.length; i++ ) {
        die1[i] = (int)(6.0*Math.random() + 1.0); //Generate random # between 1-6
        die2[i] = (int)(6.0*Math.random() + 1.0);
        System.out.println("***Roll " + i + "***");
        System.out.print("Dice one rolled: " + die1[i] + ", dice two rolled: " + die2[i] + "\n") ;
        dieSum = die1[i] + die2[i];
        System.out.println("Total rolled was: " + dieSum + "\n");

    }
}
```

}

Thanks a lot for taking a peek at this for me, and excuse my freshness to the site and programming in general.

Comment: I'd like to add that so far my code is successful in simulating the rolling of two dice and adding their sum for the amount of trials decided by the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep track of two more variables: `int biggestStreak, currentStreak` (initialized with 1).

After you rolled the dice and and stored the variables, you can check if your roll is the same as the roll before and increase `currentStreak`:

```
int lastDieSum = die1[i-1] + die2[i-1];

if (lastDieSum == dieSum) {
     currentStreak++;
     if (currentStreak > biggestStreak) {
         biggestStreak = currentStreak;
     } 
} else {
     currentStreak = 1;
}
```

The last bit now also stores the current streak in `biggestStreak` if it is bigger than the biggest streak. Finally, the current streak is set back to zero when the value isn't the same anymore as the `lastDieSum`.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks very much, this makes a lot of sense with the way my code is already laid out. Shouldn't the streak variables be initialized to 1? I tried implementing this into my code but it only seems to display the streak as whatever I have it initialized to.

Comment: You are right. You always have a streak of one when rolling dices. Where exactly did you add the code? Inside the for loop?

Comment: apologies I'm having a lot of trouble formatting the code for these comments. yes I added it inside my for loop, I figured it needed to be in there for it to calculate for each roll.

Comment: One of your closing curved brackets is wrong. The final else statement belongs to the first if, not the nested one. Compare to my answer, there need to be two "}" in front of the else.

Comment: I copied it how you posted. I messed with it some more and scrolled up in a test run to see that it does start to collect streaks (could only find examples up to 2) but then for some reason resets to 1 if the streak is broken. I'm about to leave for work, I'll test more and post later. Thank you!

Comment: I edited the code as I messed up the formatting because I'm writing this on my phone. Make sure to have those 2 closing brackets and to use biggestStreak when trying to print it out.

Comment: I tested some more things and found that I made a silly mistake. I was in a hurry to test your code and initialized the streak variables inside the loop, making sure that every time the loop passed through it reset everything to 1 :). Moved the initialization to the beginning of my code and it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One pretty simple solution would be to create two more variables in your code.

One that holds the current streak, and another that holds the previous dieSum.

Everytime you finish a roll run an if statement that compares the current dieSum with the previous dieSum and if they are equal, increase your streak, else just set your streak back to 0.