# RollingDice Java Program Longest Streak

Tags: java, dice

Can someone help me figure out how to make this program display the longest streak. I'm rolling two dice, and recording the percent each dice sum. Now I need something that will tell me what dice sum came up in the longest streak for example "The longest run was a run of 8 7's that began at roll 1479966."

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class RollThoseDice {
    /* Author: Name
     * Assignment: Third Program
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
    int timesRolled, randomOutSum;
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat ("#.###");

    System.out.println("Name: "
                + "\nAssignment: Third Program"
                +"\nExtra Credit: Percentage is displayed in three decimal places");

    int[] d = new int[13];
    for (int i = 2; i < 13; i++) d[i] = 0;

    int N=0;
    boolean againA = true;
    while(againA) {
        try{
            System.out.print("\nHow Many Rolls? ");
            N =kbd.nextInt();
            againA = false;

        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Input");
            kbd.next();
        }
    }   

    for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) {
    int diceOut1 = (int) (Math.random()*6+1);
    int diceOut2 = (int) (Math.random()*6+1);

       int diceSum = diceOut1 + diceOut2;
       d[diceSum]++;       
    }

    for (int i = 2; i < 13; i++)

       System.out.println("Total " + i + " happened "
               + df.format((double) (d[(int) i] / (double) N) * 100) 
               + "% of the time.");
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: Appears to be a duplicate of [Basic Java Dice program - trouble finding longest streak](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28354928/basic-java-dice-program-trouble-finding-longest-streak).

Answer (score 0):

> The longest run was a run of 8 7's that began at roll 1479966.

So, what are the parameters in that output?

Looks like roll, run length or roll count, and roll number.

Hmm, what can keep multiple variables, so we can treat them as one thing?

I know, we'll create a **model class**.

```
public class RollStreak {

    private final NumberFormat NF = NumberFormat.getInstance();

    private int roll;
    private int rollCount;

    private long rollNumber;

    public RollStreak(int roll, long rollNumber, int rollCount) {
        this.roll = roll;
        this.rollNumber = rollNumber;
        this.rollCount = rollCount;
    }

    public int getRoll() {
        return roll;
    }

    public int getRollCount() {
        return rollCount;
    }

    public long getRollNumber() {
        return rollNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("The computer rolled a ");
        builder.append(roll);
        builder.append(" ");
        builder.append(rollCount);
        builder.append(" times in a row starting at roll number ");
        builder.append(NF.format(rollNumber));
        builder.append(".");

        return builder.toString();
    }

}
```

A model class allows you to treat a group of fields as one object.

I don't want to give away the whole answer.  You still have to determine how to create these model class instances and get the longest streaks.  Hint: There can be more than one longest streak.